# SignalR not working after deploy on azure.Works on localhost

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

[image]

so if got this error after deploying. The chat page thats located on localhost/Home/Chat opens fine when i run it in local host but i get status code 500 when i try to open it azurewebsites.net

```
  app.UseEndpoints(
                endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapHub<SignalRChatHub>("/chat");
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                    });
```

Those are my endpoints in startup.

Thats the JS in the view

```
<script>
        var connection =
            new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl("https://myurl.azurewebsites.net/Home/Chat")
                .build();
        connection.on("NewMessage",
            function (message) {
                var chatInfo = `<div  style="color:black;text-align:center;font-size: 25px">${message.user} says :  ${escapeHtml(message.text)}</div>`;
                $("#messagesList").append(chatInfo);
            });
```

i replaced the WithUrl with my url(i didnt post it here because its not ready :D) but still nothing

Thats my home controller

```
 public IActionResult Chat()
        {
            return this.View();
        }
```

i suspect it got something to do with Connection string and that is getting the dafault connection from the db and not the one from the Azure db. But dont know how to fix that...

Comment: The error message in the picture you provided is very clear as what is causing the issue.  When you deploy you need to set the Environmental Variable.

Comment: The Environmental Variable is set to production. i dont understand what to do next

Comment: From cmd.exe use >Set which will give all  the environmental variables and values.  From the start button in windows type ENVIRON and get utility to set users variables.

Answer (score 1):

Okay got it going ! The first problem was that Environmental Variable in azure was set to Production and thats why the error looked like that changed the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in Azure,AppService,Configuration,Application Settings. From Production to Development and got the more convinient error.The error was that it couldnt find the View.I have the view in the folder it searched but it didnt work. The fix was right click on the view and changing the Build Action to Content.This fixed my issue.